# Drag and drop from Picasa to Keynote?

Tags: macos, picasa, iwork-keynote

Does anyone know how to drag and drop photos from Picasa for Mac into a Keynote slide?  I know you can do this from iPhoto, but in general I like Picasa much better.

Answer (score 2):

I use rightclick show-in-finder all the time, remember to SAVE first (eg clicking the disk icon) or you will be using the unedited file!

Picasa definitely should add the function to "export" the photo you hold when you drag it outside the window, thus letting you have a copy of the edited file in hand, ready to drop in any app

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't just work out of the box, it's probably just because of the code in Picasa. That app is very cross-platform, so it's likely they didn't take the time to add the Mac-specific code that would allow it to interact with your system in such a way.

<strike>Anyhow, I'm sure drag-and-drop works to the Finder (and *from* the Finder for Keynote), so really, that's what your Desktop is for!</strike> (**Edit:** evidently not)

Comment: Nope, this does not work.  Open up Picasa and try it.  Dragging a photo to the desktop or a Finder window does nothing.  You could obviously import a folder in Picasa, drag the photo to that folder _within_ Picasa, go to the folder in Finder, and drag from Finder to Keynote, but that's more work than simply dragging the photo itself (particularly for a large presentation with lots of pictures).

Comment: -1 for posting an answer without even opening up the application to see what the difficulty was.

Comment: @David Somewhat ironically, I actually _tried_; on my machine Picasa hangs after the EULA. So I'm not exactly convinced it's written with full Mac nativity in mind, hence my answer. I do contest that my answer is in fact incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for following up.  I've removed the "-1".  Looks like the best solution (unless someone else posts something) is going to be to find a way to synchronize the iPhoto and Picasa libraries, and then just drag and drop from iPhoto.  It's messy, but it would work.

Comment: @David Thanks--One other option comes to mind (at least according to [this Google support answer](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=19554)) is that there may be a "show in finder" option that comes up when you control-click (or right-click) a photo in Picasa, from which you could then drag to Keynote. That might streamline the process if you don't want to deal with iPhoto.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is to place the photos you want to use in keynote, on your desktop, from picasa, and THEN simply drag them from the DT into the open keynote window.